# Policy regarding grouping of papers in Google Scholar

Tags: bibliometrics, google-scholar

Using Google scholar, a researcher can generate a public webpage where all his papers and citations are presented.
Because Google is far from perfect, it is possible to group some papers. For instance if the same paper is (wrongly) seen as two papers by Google scholar, it is possible to make a fusion : the two papers are now a unique one, and the citation are recomputed accordingly.

My question : when there is a conference version, an extended journal version and possibly a invited conference version of the same work, is it best to merge all the versions or all the papers are to be considered different ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One rule of thumb would be that any set of related papers that would be considered separate for a paper CV should be considered separate in what amounts to an electronic CV. Especially if one version clearly contains more material/data/argument than another one.